# Visual Studio Code - filename color

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason, after the update, some filenames appear yellow.
[image]

How do I disable it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"git.decorations.enabled": false
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_git-status-in-file-explorer

Answer (score 4):

As part of the update, Visual Studio Code integrates the colour highlighting of Git version control into the main file explorer.

That’s why you’re seeing yellow for some files as changes have been made to them that have not yet been committed in Git.

You can remove the colour highlighting by adding this line to your settings.json file in VS Code, accessible via Preferences.

`"git.decorations.enabled": false`

If you wish, you can disable the Git integration entirely by adding these lines to the settings.json file instead.

```
{
...
  // Disable Git
  "git.enabled": false,
  "git.path": null,
  "git.autofetch": false
}
```

Comment: I was going to say that suggesting disabling git altogether is a bit extreme, except in the OP's image there is no git icon so perhaps he doesn't use it.  However, -1 for editing your answer to include @Alex's previous answer without properly crediting him.

Comment: Yes, you're right Mark. Apologies to @Alex, I didn't see his answer when editing mine since I was on a mobile browser and it hadn't shown the updated list of answers. I found it in a blog post online.

Answer (score 3):

To generally disable the colors in the explorer, one can use the setting:

```
User/Features/Explorer/Decorations/Colors: false
```