# What does green folder mean?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My folder is a NodeJS project. After `npm install` and committing/pushing, I still see `node_modules` green. Some of its subfolders are also green.

Checking status of my git, it's `up-to-date`.

What's wrong with my `node_modules`. How to commit it?

Please note that I commented out `node_modules/` in `.gitignore`

I referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301338/what-does-green-folder-icon-in-github-web-interface-mean), but it does not seem to connect with my issue.

Regards[image]

Comment: why would you comment out `node_modules` in `.gitignore`? What is the use of putting that directory in the repository? You can recreate it with the content of `package.json`. Now you need to start from scratch with a new repository to get rid of all those useless content in the repository database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Files in a folder are highlighted green with a number 1 next to them. What does this signify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713409/files-in-a-folder-are-highlighted-green-with-a-number-1-next-to-them-what-does)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code - filename color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47290359/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

As you said "I commented out node_modules/ in .gitignore"
VSCode consider node_modules/ as newly added folder to your project.

**Green Color indicates newly added file/folder to the git in VSCode.**