# Disable dimming / graying out of files & folders which are not in the workspace in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

We are currently running a [meta](https://github.com/mateodelnorte/meta) repo, which is causing VSCode to believe that files & folders are not in our workspace, even though they actually are.  Due to this, I am trying to determine how I can stop VSCode from dimming out files & folders which are not in the workspace, such as `node_modules` in the screenshot below:

[image: VSCode explorer]

Thanks!

Comment: It may help if you put the **why** in your question too... What's the (actual) problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @RobIII, I have added some context, even though it's unrelated to the screenshot.

Comment: It still explains nothing. Which problem (other than "I don't like gray text") are you trying to solve? But, hey, maybe that's just me.

Comment: I would say it's an accessibility concern, as it's difficult for me to read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code - filename color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290359/visual-studio-code-filename-color)

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, that setting`"git.decorations.enabled": false`  has no effect on the dimmed files or folders in the Explorer.  Whether that is a regression from prior behaviour I am not sure.  But if it once worked, it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files or folders in your `.gitignore` file will get dimmed out.  I haven't found a way to avoid that with a specific SCM or git setting other than to disable the generic setting:

`Explorer > Decorations: Colors`

but then you will lose the altered colors of modified files too for example, which might be acceptable.

I would think the `Git > Decorations: Enabled` setting might affect that dimmed-out color but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Excellent--thanks Mark, I really appreciate the detailed answer!